# In an alert dialog, how can I reduce the spacing between the 'message' and my view?

Tags: android, android-layout

For example, the following code:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
builder.setTitle("foo");
builder.setMessage("bar");
EditText edit = new EditText(activity);
builder.setView(edit);
builder.show();
```

[Results in this dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VF7Z6.png)

As can be seen, there is a large vertical space between the message and the edit text. I would like to reduce it, ideally without having to use a custom layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we display the *AlertDialog* in an emulator and show the component tree in the Layout Inspector, we see that the extra space comes from a *Space* widget called "textSpacerNoButtons"

[image]

and a *FrameLayout* named "customPanel" that holds the *EditText*

[image]

The *Space* widget has a specified height of `18dp` (which we shall see in a moment) while the *FrameLayout* has a minimum height of `48dp` which can be seen in the attributes of the Layout Inspector.

The layout used by *AlertDialog* is [alert_dialog_material.xml](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog_material.xml;l=1?q=alert_dialog_materi&sq=&ss=android%2Fplatform%2Fsuperproject). I have copied the relevant portions below:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/contentPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="48dp">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:clipToPadding="false">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Space
                android:id="@+id/textSpacerNoTitle"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_padding_top_material" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/message"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingEnd="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
                android:paddingStart="?attr/dialogPreferredPadding"
                style="@style/TextAppearance.Material.Subhead" />

            <Space
                android:id="@+id/textSpacerNoButtons"
                android:visibility="gone"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/dialog_padding_top_material" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</FrameLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/customPanel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="48dp">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/custom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</FrameLayout>
```

For the *Space* widget, the height is defined as `@dimen/dialog_padding_top_material` which is `18dp` in the example. Changing this value has other implications, so we will leave it alone.

So, that is the source of the space but how to fix it? The way I would prefer is to use a custom view even if it is a near exact copy of "alert_dialog_material.xml". If that is not acceptable, then we must make changes on-the-fly to remove the minimum height of *contentPanel* and to set the *Space* widget's visibility to `gone`.

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("foo");
builder.setMessage("bar");
EditText edit = new EditText(this);
builder.setView(edit);
AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.show();
View decorview = alertDialog.getWindow().getDecorView();
View view = decorview.findViewById(R.id.contentPanel);
view.setMinimumHeight(0);
view = decorview.findViewById(R.id.textSpacerNoButtons);
view.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

[image]

Comment: How did you get the alert dialog to show up in the layout inspector? [Question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69579816/how-do-i-inspect-the-layout-of-an-alert-dialog-using-layout-inspector)